# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'mode' when using Tsseract OCR in Python

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I intended to import an image file from my computer and then use Tesseract OCR to recignize the characters in the image.I used Google Colab to run the code.

The code I wrote

```
    !apt install tesseract-ocr libtesseract-dev tesseract-ocr-jpn
    !pip install pyocr

    from PIL import Image
    import pyocr
    import cv2
    from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

    from google.colab import files
    uploaded=files.upload()

    tools=pyocr.get_available_tools()
    print(tools)
    tool=tools[0]
    print(tool.get_name())

    txt1 = tool.image_to_string(
    uploaded,
    lang='jpn+eng',
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder(tesseract_layout=6)
    )
```

After running the code above, the error message`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'mode'` appeared.

Below is all of the error message shown by colab

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-2ad0a8585335> in <module>
      2     uploaded,
      3     lang='jpn+eng',
----> 4     builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder(tesseract_layout=6)
      5     )
      6 help(dict.items)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyocr/tesseract.py in image_to_string(image, lang, builder)
    362         builder = builders.TextBuilder()
    363     with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
--> 364         if image.mode != "RGB":
    365             image = image.convert("RGB")
    366         image.save(os.path.join(tmpdir, "input.bmp"))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

I have searched for this and although there are same cases on the Internet with similar error messages`'dict' object has no attribute '~'`, I couldn't find any case that was regarding the attribute "mode."

***Could you please tell me why this error happened?***

I appreciate it if you could leave any comments or answers.

Answer (score 0):

`files.upload()` returns a dict in the format of `{filename : raw_data}`, so you will want to pass only the values of the dict in the image parameter of `image_to_string`, instead of the entire dict.

If you know you will only ever be uploading one image file, then you could do something like:

```
    img = list(uploaded.values())[0]  # This is a bit of a hack
    txt1 = tool.image_to_string(
    img,
    lang='jpn+eng',
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder(tesseract_layout=6)
    )
```

A better solution would be to loop over all of your uploaded files, even if there is only one:

```
!apt install tesseract-ocr libtesseract-dev tesseract-ocr-jpn
!pip install pyocr

from PIL import Image
import pyocr
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

from google.colab import files
uploaded=files.upload()

tools=pyocr.get_available_tools()
print(tools)
tool=tools[0]
print(tool.get_name())

for fn, filedata in uploaded.items():
    print(f"Processing file {fn}...")
    process_image(filedata)

def process_image(image):
    txt1 = tool.image_to_string(
            image,
            lang='jpn+eng',
            builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder(tesseract_layout=6)
        )
    # Do whatever you want to do with txt1 here. or return it and handle in the loop above
```